# Entity framework core - wouldn't use migrations

Tags: migration, .net-assembly, entity-framework-core

I wish to use ef without migrations! I would like to manipulate the tables and cols manually. Is this possible?

Don't find a solutions for that problem.

I would like to do this so, because my entity-models are in different assymblys.

Comment: You can use Scaffolding if you wish to use Database First modelling - but it is unclear what you are after.

Comment: I still wish code first modelling, but i want to add/alter tables by code not by migrations.

Comment: So you want to handle database schema updates yourself? But still want to be able to create the initial db schema from your code based model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code First model and handle schema changes/updates using CREATE and ALTER commands.

You can build the initial database schema from your model by using:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

To ensure the database schema is up to date, you can either add a version table with a singel versinnumber column/row and update as versions increase, or always run the same idempotent SQL script on application launch with existance checks and the CREATE and ALTER statements

Comment: And how can i handle versioning? Can you give me a little bit more example?